# Visual Studio 2008 saving files gets slow

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've looked for some other articles on this problem and even tried some of the ideas in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations#8539); however, nothing has solved the issue yet.  So, on to the issue.

Something happens when working in Visual Studio (usually C#) that causes the IDE to become a bit wonky when saving a file.  I will be working along just fine for a while then at some point I notice that every time I save a file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)  it becomes very slow.

The behavior I notice is this; I hit save in some fashion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, menu, etc...) and in the status bar I see the word **Searching** show up.  It looks like it is scanning through all of the loaded namespaces for something, although I have no idea for what or why it is doing so.  It causes a real hiccup in workflow since typically I will hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> often and keep typing.

I have been unable to track down what exactly causes this to start happening.  It has happened in multiple project types (web, WPF, console).

Has anyone seen this behavior or have any suggestions?

Comment: I have similar issue with Visual C++ 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a problem similar to this happen before. Are you using an plugins like ReSharper or DevExpress?

Comment: I do have a DevExpress installed.  I hadn't realized it was still there as it does not show up i nmy add-ins list for some reason.

Comment: I have not had the problem since uninstalling DevExpress.  It would normally have occurred again by this time.  Thanks!

Comment: I have both DevEx and ReSharper installed, I see one of my page is taking more than 30 seconds to save. I tried disabling ReSharper but no luck. Is there anything i can do with DevEx or anything ?

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is old but this may help others who are having the same issue.

I to had a problem with VS 2008 taking long time to save some files. Not all files, just a few files. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>would take any where from 30-120 seconds.

I figured out it was on pages having external JavaScript. So I selectively commented them out and tried saving and found the offender.

Culprit was Google translate javascript code.

It starts with `<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a...`

Notice the `//` at the beginning of the src. All other external scripts that started with **http://** had no problem, I changed the // to http:// and the problem was solved.

It seems VS is trying to get the file locally if the path is not http. I don't know what it does, but this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable intellsense?  We've seen that bog down all sorts of things in Visual Studio.

Comment: I just tried removing DeveExpress.  If my problem does not go away, I will try turning Intellisense off, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Visual Studio 2005.

I read through several posts (sorry I could not post the links because of: sorry, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink).

I ran FileMon and discovered that on save the IDE keeps querying 
C:\Documents and Settings\iguigova\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Then I came across this post: 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=347228

Now I am trying to clear the directory. It was FULL. I plan to set a batch file to delete its contents daily...

Good luck!